# Processing the output from Perl script

Tags: regex, perl, telnet

With this code the result in the log file is always the total output.

I also tried passing the regex expression inside a variable but without luck.

The idea is to print into a log file all of the output from the command until it reaches a line that starts with `known`.

Please share your ideas or what you'd consider the proper approach.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::Telnet;

my $telnet = new Net::Telnet( Timeout => 10, Errmode => 'die' );
my $logfile = 'Rogues.log';
my @hosts;
my $debug = 1;

$hosts[0] = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx';

$telnet->open( "$hosts[0]" ) or die $telnet->errmsg;

$telnet->waitfor( '/Please login: $/i' );
$telnet->print( 'USERHERE' ) or die $telnet->errmsg;

$telnet->waitfor( '/Password: $/i' );
$telnet->print( 'PASSWORDHERE' ) or die $telnet->errmsg;

$telnet->waitfor( '/XXXX>/' );
$telnet->cmd( 'enable' ) or die $telnet->errmsg;

my @output = $telnet->cmd( 'show rogue-devices' ) or die $telnet->errmsg;

$telnet->close();

foreach my $index ( @output ) {

    if ( ( $index ne /^Known\/Recognized\sRogue\sDevices:/ )
            || ( $index ne /^User\sBlocked\sRogue\sDevices:/ ) ) {

        if ( $debug ) { }

        open( my $fh, '>>', 'ZD_Rogues.log' ) or die "Could not open file $logfile $!";
        print $fh "\n $index";
        close $fh;
    }
}

print "Export Finished. $logfile";
```

### Update

Hi, the output is made of 3 groups. "Current Active Rogue Devices" followed by "Known/Recognized Rogue Devices" then followed by "User Blocked Rogue Devices:" all with the same content: Rogue Devices: Mac Address= XXX Channel= XXX Radio= XXX Type= XXX Encryption= XXX SSID= XXX Last Detected= XXX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exit the loop using [last](https://www.tu-chemnitz.de/docs/perldoc/functions/last.html) when you reach one of your stop lines. Note that regexes match case-sensitively... if you want to be case-insensitive, add the `i` flag to the end of your regex: `/regex/i`.

```
for my $index (@output) {
    last if $index =~ /^Known\/Recognized Rogue Devices/
         || $index =~ /^User Blocked Rogue Devices/;

    print "$index\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Update

Your question is very unclear. You say

> The idea is to print into a log file all of the output from the command until it reaches a line that starts with known

Does this work?

```
for ( @output ) {
    last if /^known/i;
    print;
}
```

### Original post

You are using the string inequality operator `ne` instead of the pattern binding operator `!~`

Like so

```
if ( $index !~ /^Known\/Recognized\sRogue\sDevices:/
        or $index !~ /^User\sBlocked\sRogue\sDevices:/ ) {

    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Borodin, thank you for the fast reply, I've also tried it with !~ no luck. I still get the 2 lines printed in the logs.
Both "Known/Recognized Rogue Devices:" and "User Blocked Rogue DeviceS:", also tried without /s and passing the content into vars.

Comment: The goal is to actually stop the printing when it reaches a line with the Known... content, although for starters i was trying to simply not print those two lines. Maybe I'm still doing something wrong. In any case i tried again and replicated with your contribution but it's still printing them both.

Comment: Can you please confirm the my regex is proper ? Thanks again!

Comment: @FilhoDumMocho: Your question is very unclear, but I've added to my solution. It would help *enormously* if you could drop the Telnet stuff and show the expected contents of `@output` and the corresponding output that you want

Comment: I wonder if there's leading whitespace on the array elements. Either way, @Borodin's most simplistic example will be the guide.

Comment: @FilhoDumMocho: Your code doesn't correspond with your stated intention, If you have come to Stack Overflow to get some work done for free then please go away. With any luck your question will soon be closed anyway, and I regret the time that I spent hoping to help you

Comment: Hi, the output is made of 3 groups.

"Current Active Rogue Devices" followed by

"Known/Recognized Rogue Devices" then followed by 

"User Blocked Rogue Devices:" all with the same content:


   Rogue Devices:

   Mac Address= XXX

   Channel= XXX

   Radio= XXX

   Type= XXX

   Encryption= XXX

   SSID= XXX

   Last Detected= XXX

Comment: @FilhoDumMocho: And how do you think you should modify the code you have shown to make that work? I've modified your question to include that information, but I doubt if you will get much more help unless you show some sign that you have made an effort to solve this yourself

Comment: @Borodin , I've been sweating for 2 days changing back and forth.
Right now this is what I've got after everyone's input. 
But now it's not even creating the log anymore. ^_^' 

`for my $index (@output) {

 last if $index !~ /^Known\/Recognized Rogue Devices/

or $index !~ /^User locked Rogue Devices/;

print "\n$index";

open (my $fh, '>>', 'ZD_Rogues.log') or die "Could not open file $logfile $!";

print $fh "\n $index";

close $fh;

}`

Comment: @Borodin and thanks again for the feedback and for trying to help. Much appreciated

Comment: @Borodin also the output as you requested is the one i posted before, although i swapped the values with XXX since it also includes mac-address etc.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, you want to use the != operator. But you also have the wrong logic operator - you are using 'or' (||) when you should using 'and' (&&).

Comment: Hi Ken, Thank you for your input, although i don't think it's the case. I need when it's one or the other they will never be seen in a single line.
I'm thinking maybe the problem is the logic afterwards and not with the regex itself.
Correct me again please if i'm wrong.
The output of the file would be something like:

Comment: made of 3 groups "Current Active Rogue Devices" followed by "Known/Recognized Rogue Devices" 
then followed as well by yet another group "User Blocked Rogue Devices:", which would have, again the same structure or would be empty too.
The idea is to get only the first group "Active...".

Comment: "Current Active Rogue Devices:"
   Rogue Devices:
     Mac Address= XXX
     Channel= XXX
     Radio= XXX
     Type= XXX
     Encryption= XXX
     SSID= XXX
     Last Detected= XXX
"Known/Recognized Rogue Devices:"
 same structure
"User Blocked Rogue Devices:"
 same structure

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Borodin, @stevieb, @Ken Slater and @toolic, for your feedback and time.
I apologize if i didn't explain myself correctly in the first place as well.

```
    for my $index (@output) {
      open (my $fh, '>>', 'ZD_Rogues.log') or die "Could not open file $logfile $!";
      last if $index =~ /Known/;
      print $fh "\n $index";
      close $fh;
    }
```

The result with the above is indeed, all lines are exported into the log file stopping when it reaches the line with the "Known".